# days of the week in the same month, moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

is there any way to get the days of a week that belong to a same month from a Date Object?

I mean, if saturday is 1 and sunday 2, the week would be just 1 and 2 in a week from monday to sunday. The days from monday to friday would be a previous week form me in this example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understand you correctly you are looking for something like this

```
var startDate = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var endDate = startDate.endOf('week');
var numberOfDaysInBetween = startDate.diff(endDate, 'days');
```

to include the start day add +1 to number of days in between